# XML for Checked List Item in a ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, checkbox

I've been searching all over for an example of the XML needed to setup a ListView to use a checkbox.  While I've been able to find the Java code needed, the XML for the list items remains surprisingly elusive.  Are there any good resources to learn how to style these listitems appropriately?

When I tried modifying the base XML file I have, I got the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

So I'm not sure how to create it on my own using more elements than just a TextView.  So currently, I am using the integer value found here as the resource ID for the ArrayAdapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#simple_list_item_checked

which looks like what I want, but I need to be able to find the XML for that resource and style it for my own needs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a layout of your own and inflate the same. But, for this you need to write a customized code for Adapter.

[Here is one good example to start.](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026071253/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/08/custom-view-in-your-listactivity-and.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for the Java code--I'm looking for how I can modify the list item XML (the resource ID of which is passed to the ArrayAdapter).  Currently, if I try and make anything but the most basic list item XML (with a TextView as the root element), I get the following error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"