# Custom list adapter, access to android.R resource

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a view for the list item programatically - it needs to be similar to the original android check box template - here is the android original template xml:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```

Here is my source:

```
CheckedTextView ctv = new CheckedTextView(context);
ctv.setId(CTV_ID);
ctv.setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.attr.textCheckMark);
ctv.setPadding(Utils.toDP(4, context), Utils.toDP(4, context), Utils.toDP(4, context), Utils.toDP(4, context));
```

Thre problem is with `setCheckMarkDrawable` line, I get exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1010046
```

It obviously that my code cannot access this resource.
What should I do, what am I doing wrong, how to fix this?

Comment: put your drwawable in the resource drawable folder and refer to it as R.drawable.myimage. Try this

Comment: I don't want to do that, everything else is dynamically created from code and I dont want to make exception for this  one

Comment: what is the location of the template you mention in the sdk ?

Comment: Not sure where is in sdk, here is the online source:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990234/xml-for-checked-list-item-in-a-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the solution:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textCheckMark, typedValue, true);
return typedValue.resourceId; // <- This is the actual resource id to be used
```

It seems that this value needs to be resolved to current theme resource id.
Similar problem: [background issue with styles and themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675231/background-issue-with-styles-and-themes/14524876#14524876)